# mouse cursor leaves blender window when using walk/fly navigation

Tags: 3d-view, windows, navigation

whenever I use the walk/fly mode I cant move my cursor too much or else it will go off the screen on to another monitor. sometimes the viewport even appears upside down or some other odd way. is there some sort of box I can check to fix this?

Comment: Have you found a solution? The same happens for me. Blender 3.3 broke the feature in my environment.

Comment: nope. still searching